# Facebook invite mysql hierarchical queries instead use postgresql

Tags: mysql, facebook, postgresql

I've seen few posts here saying I can do hierarchical queries using mysql.

I've not used PostgreSQL, yet. If I change to PostgreSQL, do I have to change a lot of syntax or can I do that hierarchical stuff in MySQL itself?

[Hierarchical queries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/mysql-hierarchical-queries)

What sender sends is Facebook invite so can I do this in SQL?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood:I've not got an proper answer to the above question.

Comment: What kind of hierarchical queries are you doing in MySQL? Please, be more specific in what you want to achieve. There are many ways of represening and querying hierarchical data in SQL. Postgres supplies many of them...

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have recursive queries, databases like [PostgreSQL](http://old.storytotell.org/blog/2009/08/11/postgresql84-recursive-queries.html), SQL Server and Oracle do have these types of queries. Very powerful and easy to use, but in MySQL you're on your own.

You could use a work around like a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model), works in almost any database but is not as fast.