# How to make kind of IF in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, that need to be joined.
They look like this

[image]

[image]

I need to join them so I have all the data from both tables and then display the information like this - IF there is German translation, display ONLY German. If there is no German, display English (Which is available for all the objects)

Comment: What rdms are you using?

Comment: what is expected output

Comment: Are you linking from another table to this table?

Comment: Im using MySql and expected output would be entry names of ids 1,2,3 on german (if there is german 1,2,3) or names on english with same ids, if there is no german translation in the database

Comment: No, im not linking anything. there is only this one table and there are objects which dont have german translation so i need to use english. but if one object have both eng and german, they will have same ID and i need to pick german one

Comment: Well Mr. Trent, go and charge it somewhere else. This is a place for helping eachother. I made several atempts, most of which failed. So i guess no point  of writing my failed attempts here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT f1.id,f1.lang,f1.name
FROM foo AS f1
LEFT JOIN foo AS f2
ON f1.id=f2.id AND f1.lang<>f2.lang AND f2.lang='ger'
WHERE f2.id IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a75/9

If there are more than just english and german language the last line should be changed to

```
WHERE f2.id IS NULL AND (f1.lang='ger' OR f1.lang='eng')
```

Comment: Nice approach, currently fails if you add a [third language](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f936/1/0)

Comment: @Andomar Yes it does,could be fixed by changing the last line to`WHERE f2.id IS NULL AND (f1.lang='ger' OR f1.lang='eng')` but the question doesn't really talk about third language so I didn't think it would be a problem. If there are more languages it should probably look entirely diffrent and have preference for that other language too. Thanks for your input, edited.

Comment: Hey man, Im rly not that good at sql, so I would have to ask you 1 more question. Can you do the same thing, but if we have 2 tables, that needs to be joined.
they would look like this: 

CREATE TABLE foo
 (`id` int, `lang` varchar(3), `name` varchar(16))
;
 
INSERT INTO foo
 (`id`, `lang`, `name`)
VALUES
 (1, 'eng', 'Prio 1 tasks'),
 (2, 'eng', 'Prio 2 tasks'),
 (1, 'ger', 'Prio 1 Ausfgaben')
;

CREATE TABLE foo2
 (`id` int, `parent_id` int)
;
 
INSERT INTO foo
 (`id`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
 (3,1 ),
 (4,1 ),
 (5,2 )
;

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what parent_id is or how do you want to join it. Like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf9c7/2 ?

Comment: This is a database from which i form a treeView. So parent ID is an id of a parent node. If it's 0, than it's the prime node

Comment: @StefanBrankovic I'm not really how it's connected to this question. If you want to use it with a hierarchical query you sure can, at worst you can just put it in brackets and use as a subquery. If you want to know how to do a hierarchical query you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8111762/2115135

Comment: I need to make a treeView looking something like this: http://tinypic.com/r/5v7ghh/6
 If you can notice, first 6 master-nodes, are the nodes with the same ID but in diferent language, german and english (as you can see from the database i put above). Now, i need to join the two tables and filter the german translations and show only them, like you did before, but using single table. Have I made myself more clear now ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26057/discussion-between-stefan-brankovic-and-jakub-kania)

Answer (score 3):

```
select  eng.entryid
,       coalesce(ger.name, eng.name)
from    YourTable eng
left join
        YourTable ger
on      ger.entryid = eng.entryid
        and ger.lang = 'ger'
where   eng.lang = 'eng'
```

Comment: I dont have two different tables...all the data is in the 1 table with both english and german translations or only english one

Comment: The table is used twice in a self-join.  But it's still one table called `YourTable`.  The left side of the self-join is aliased as `eng` and the right side as `ger`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select entry_id,
       case max(lang)
           when 'ger' then max(case lang when 'ger' then name end)
           else max(name)
       end as trans_name
from your_table
group by entry_id
```

Comment: This would fail with the addition of Zwahili as a language

Comment: @Andomar: True, but there's no indication that the OP wants to deal with more than two languages, let alone *how* he would want to deal with more than two. (The simplest answer would be simply to include a `where lang in ('ger', 'eng')` clause, but from the question even that doesn't appear to be necessary.)