# SQL / Self Join / Number of Subordinates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called 'employees' with some data like employee id, employee name and manager id.
I have self joined it to show the number of subordinates under each manager.

It looks like this and it works fine: [SQL fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f015/1)

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  emp_id INT,
  emp_name VARCHAR(16),
  mgr_id INT,

  );


INSERT INTO employees VALUES 
(1,'George',5),
(2,'Monica',5),
(3,'Rachel',5),
(4,'Marie',5),
(5,'Emma',6),
(6,'David',NULL);
```

And the query itself that shows the number of direct subordinates grouped by manager is this:

```
SELECT

  m.emp_name,
  COUNT(e.emp_name) AS number_of_subordinates

FROM

  employees as e
  JOIN employees as m
  ON e.mgr_id=m.emp_id

GROUP BY m.emp_name
ORDER BY number_of_subordinates DESC
```

However, this shows me the direct subordinates of each manager. What I want to be able to show as well is the number of indirect subordinates. So, for example, whilst Emma would still have 4 subordinates, David would have the 4 Emma has plus Emma which equals 5 (since he's Emma's boss and Emma is the boss of George, Monica, Rachel and Marie.

Comment: Please post your query into your question itself. If the linked SQLFiddle goes stale, this question becomes worthless to future visitors (edit: thank you)

Comment: You need to do a recursive or hierarchical query.  MySQL has basically no support for these queries.  To do what you want, you need to use a stored procedure (or change the data structure or use a different database engine).

Comment: If you just want a set depth, say only sub-ordinates up to 2 levels, you can just do a join for each depth. However, if you want it to work for all trees, you need a recursive query, which MySQL doesn't support out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [recursive self join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_join). This is not supported in MySQL, although it is in a number of other DBMSs (Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, DB2, PostgreSQL etc.).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111762/1669475) provides a way to get around this, although it is not ideal, as described in its comments. Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/) discuss alternative ways of representing hierarchical data in MySQL.

Source: [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins)

Comment: Thanks!! I'm new to SQL so not sure how to do a recursive join :( And I need to be able to do this by tomorrow. Any volunteers to quickly show me how I can do this in this example? :)

Comment: You can't do one in MySQL. Unless you want to switch to another DBMS, or change your database structure, you'll probably have to use the method I suggested to get around it. See the answer I linked.

Comment: I am looking at that but struggling to understand how it would work in my case. Like I said, I'm a newbie and not quite good at decoding stuff yet.