# Use value from first select for second select in union?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

Lets say I've got the following table which is a familiar example.

```
+----------------------------------+
|              TAGS                |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| tag_id |   tag_name  | parent_id |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|   1    | programming |    NULL   |
|   2    |     php     |      1    |
|   3    |    class    |      2    |
|   4    |    object   |      2    |
|   5    |    method   |      3    |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to devise a query which selects the associated `parent_id` and `tag_name` based on the value of the initial select statement.

**Something like this:**

```
SELECT * FROM tags AS child
WHERE child.tag_name = 'object'
UNION
SELECT * FROM tags AS parent
WHERE parent.parent_id = child.parent_id
```

I need to be able to return the combined rows from both these queries which is why I'm using `UNION`.

**The expected result should be:**

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| tag_id |   tag_name  | parent_id |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|   2    |     php     |      1    |
|   4    |    object   |      2    |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

I also think that a `JOIN` may work but I can't quite make it work.

Comment: This is called a hierarchical query. This may be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/mysql-hierarchical-queries.  Make sure to read the warning in the comment, though. This can be dangerous.

Comment: I don't understand how you got your expected results? You want all rows with the tag name 'object' (which is row 4) and you want to get rows with that same parent_id? So why aren't you only returning object and class?

Comment: Since I select object initially in the first select, I need to then select the parent (php) as a result of that first query. I know the example query is wrong so I'm looking for guidance on how to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tag_id, tag_name, parent_id  
FROM tags AS child
WHERE child.tag_name = 'object'
UNION
SELECT parent.tag_id, parent.tag_name, parent.parent_id  
FROM tags AS parent
INNER JOIN tags AS child ON parent.tag_id = child.parent_id AND child.tag_name = 'object';
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5700a/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| TAG_ID | TAG_NAME | PARENT_ID |
|--------|----------|-----------|
|      4 |   object |         2 |
|      2 |      php |         1 |
```

Comment: No result on that query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tags t1, tags t2
WHERE t1.parent_id = t2.parent_id AND t1.tag_name = 'object';
```

Comment: Just selects the same row twice.

Answer (score 0):

if you want tag_name = 'object' to return 'php', you need to equate child.parent_id to parent.tag_id (and not the parent_ids to each other)

```
...
WHERE parent.parent_id = child.parent_id
```

Comment: The problem with the query I used as an example, is that the second select doesn't recognize the child alias from the first select.