# Multi level hierarchy relation in flat table design (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

My table design is

```
users (id, username..., parent_id)
```

Data is

```
id    username      parent_id
-------------------------------
1  |  admin       | null
2  |  reseller 1  | 1
3  |  client 1    | 1
4  |  reseller 2  | 1
5  |  reseller 3  | 2
6  |  reseller 4  | 2
7  |  client 2    | 5
8  |  client 3    | 6
```

I want to get all descendants of `id` `1`

I studied [Adjacency List](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/), [Nested List](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) & Closure table design, but came to conclusion that Session based Adjacency List can be better in my situation.

I found an example at [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql)

```
SELECT  @id :=
        (
        SELECT  senderid
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   receiverid = @id
        ) AS person
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 5
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        mytable
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
```

I tried to modify this query to get my result like this

```
SELECT  group_concat(@id :=
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    users
        WHERE   parent_id = @id
        )) AS u
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 1
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        users
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
```

But it is not working. Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6284c/1)

Need help in making the query work.

This is not duplicate of [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql) as this deals with one to many relation between parent and children, and the one-to=many relation is creating problem in query.

Comment: I'm quite confused. Why won't `SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE parent_id = 1;` work for you in this scenario?

Comment: @CaptainAdams Because "Reseller 2" is a descendent of "Admin", but only indirectly. The OP wants, I believe, all children, grand children, great grand children and so on.

Comment: @CaptainAdams - I need to get all descendants i.e, children, grand children and so on and not only immediate children.

Comment: @RyanVincent - It doesn't work, and I need help in fixing that. If the parent has single child, it works, but if the parent has multiple children, the query shows error.

Comment: You're basically writing a recursive query.  A lot of databases have operators for this (CONNECT BY and START WITH in Oracle, for example, and WITH RECURSIVE in Postgres.)  Not sure if MySQL has such a feature.

Comment: MySql doesn't have one. That is why I found session variables as viable solution. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: How big is the table?  Is it something you can just load every row into memory and work with it in the middle tier?

Comment: It can grow to few thousands only, so not a killer on memory.

Comment: Yea, I don't think MySql is really built to work with hierarchical data like that, at least not write-intensive data.  Not sure on the session based approach, as I don't know MySql.  Even if it works, I'd question the performance even with a few thousand rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: @Stavr00 - Not really. My question is quite different, even though this too deals with hierarchical relations. Edited the question to explain it.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT when you are done with walking via straigtforward relational structures.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I created a function as suggested by @RolandoDBA at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `siblings` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `siblings` (GivenID INT) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET queue = GivenID;
    SET queue_length = 1;

    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
        SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);
        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
            SET queue = '';
        ELSE
            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
            SET queue = q;
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) qc
        FROM `users` WHERE parent_id = front_id) A;

        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue_length = 0;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                SET rv = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN rv;

END $$
```

And then for getting siblings / children of a parent, a simple call using the above created function, `siblings` is enough.

```
SELECT siblings(id) AS `siblings` from `users` where `id` = 1
```

This returns result as

```
siblings
---------------
2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: It gives me error `Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1,2,15,16'`. here 1,2,15,16 are my output values