# Hierarchical queries in MySQL - find all decendants

Tags: mysql, adjacency-list, hierarchical-query

The answer of [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql) provides one single query to find all ancestors of a node in a adjacency list.

Now, how do I find all decendants of a node using similar query? I tried:

```
SELECT  @id :=
        (
        SELECT  receiverid
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   senderid = @id
        ) AS person
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 5
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        mytable
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
```

I just swap senderid and receiverid, but it gives me `#2014 Commands out of sync. You can't run this command now`.

Any idea?

Comment: your schema? your recursion requirements? expected results should look like what shown chunk that you will show with an [edit] ?

Comment: Please see the post I linked to. It's the same. That post asked for finding all ancestors but I'm asking for finding all decendants. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, just show the schema, load it with some data, and show expected results. It is your question. A sqlfiddle is how people do that.