# How find oldest "ancestor" in MySQL where each row has a parent or null?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have a set of data like this:

```
ID      NAME        PARENT
----    ------      -------
1       Obj #1      NULL
2       Obj #2      1
3       Obj #3      4
4       Obj #4      2
5       Obj #5      3
6       Obj #6      NULL
7       Obj #7      6
```

So if I wanted to get them with their oldest ancestor, I'd get results like this:

```
ID      NAME        OLDEST
----    ------      -------
1       Obj #1      NULL
2       Obj #2      1
3       Obj #3      1
4       Obj #4      1
5       Obj #5      1
6       Obj #6      NULL
7       Obj #7      6
```

How would I make a query to do this?

Comment: You could use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query and transform it a bit to get the oldest ancestor.

Comment: You can't really do it with a single query in MySQL.

Comment: @Uueerdo I'm almost certain that you can. Can't find the time at the moment to prove it, though.

Comment: @KamilG.Can you give me some hints to try and find the solution myself? That link you posted doesn't work. it only goes back one level.

Comment: @KamilG. You can't do it. Not the way you've structured it, at least. However, with some modifications, you can sort-of do it. Might I suggest that you look up the "Nested Set Model"  algorithm on wikipedia? This is what I use for hierarchical data. There are other models that work, as well.

Comment: It is my understanding MS SQL has recursive queries that can, but I have never used one. But if you can get your tree into the nested set model, it becomes trivial. Otherwise you must iterate, or know the max depth as indicated by Kamil's answer.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql. I think this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Because of lack of time, I'll just present you with one solution (which isn't the best one, but works with the logic of using repeated self-joins and only if you know the upper limit of your hierarchy tree).

Here's a working [**SQL Fiddle**.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbe1a/3)

**Test data generation** (like yours, without "name" column):

```
create table tbl(id int, parent int);
insert into tbl values (1,null),(2,1),(3,4),(4,2),(5,3),(6,null),(7,6);
```

**Query** to find the oldest ancestor given a depth of 5 in hierarchy tree:

```
select
  t1.id, coalesce(t5.id, t4.id, t3.id, t2.id) as oldest
from tbl t1
left join tbl t2 on t1.parent = t2.id
left join tbl t3 on t2.parent = t3.id
left join tbl t4 on t3.parent = t4.id
left join tbl t5 on t4.parent = t5.id
order by 1;
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't know how many levels deep it can go. it's unlimited.

Comment: I might find the time tomorrow to present you with a different solution.

Comment: @KamilG Appreciate it. I do need it today, but thank you for doing this (and I'd still like to see what you come up with tomorrow as I might still be struggling with it)

Comment: @DonRhummy if time is your limit, I'd go with this solution and just for the sake of making it work (we all know the deadlines) provide for much greater depth with many joins. Later, you can always replace it to optimize it. This isn't a good practice - but we all struggle with this at work, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments recommend the "nested set" model, which was popularized in Joe Celko's SQL books. But I find that data model is hard to maintain, and it's complicated to modify the data.

I prefer a design I call "closure table" which I described in this well-received Stack Overflow answer: [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.NAME, a.ID AS OLDEST
FROM MyTable AS t
JOIN ClosureTable AS c ON t.ID = c.descendant 
JOIN MyTable AS a ON a.ID = c.ancestor
WHERE a.PARENT IS NULL;
```

I also cover this model (and other solutions) in my presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Here's the video recording of my delivering this presentation: [Models for Hierarchical Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuH5OoPC3hA).

I also wrote a chapter about hierarchical data in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1:
Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

---

If you need a query that works with your data as you currently store it, see Quassnoi's clever solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111762/20860

But admittedly, it's not a stable solution because it relies on undocumented behavior of MySQL. I'd stay away from it.

---

If you can't change the code or the table structure, and you need it today, you're going to have to go with the answer from Kamil G. even though it is limited to a fixed level of depth of the hierarchy. There's no other solution, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create a new table like that. i'd also have to alter a lot of code to keep it up to date and that's not going to happen

Answer (score 0):

I usually re-design this in *MySQL* so that table looks like this:

```
id      name
10      Obj#1
1010    Obj#2 -- parent = 10
101020  Obj#6 -- parent = 1010 -- grandparent = 10 ... etc
```

And I have a lazy SQL for your current design: (6 levels of nested, you can add more if you have deeper nesting)

```
SELECT a.id, a.NAME,
  ifnull(p6.PARENT, ifnull(p5.PARENT, ifnull(p4.PARENT, ifnull(p3.PARENT, ifnull(p2.PARENT, ifnull(p.PARENT, p.id)))))) AS PARENT
FROM 0_a2 AS a
LEFT JOIN 0_a2 AS p  ON a.PARENT  = p.id
LEFT JOIN 0_a2 AS p2 ON p.PARENT  = p2.id
LEFT JOIN 0_a2 AS p3 ON p2.PARENT = p3.id
LEFT JOIN 0_a2 AS p4 ON p3.PARENT = p4.id
LEFT JOIN 0_a2 AS p5 ON p4.PARENT = p5.id
LEFT JOIN 0_a2 AS p6 ON p5.PARENT = p6.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

[image]

Comment: Your data model would be hard to maintain if an object at lets say level 20 in hierarchy changes it's belonging all the way up.

Comment: @KamilG. Yes my design is good for well-structured design as it is quick for query. Mostly used for product categories, usually max 3 levels still easy to maintain. not suitable for eg family tree