# Query rename table for chaining back through history to get "a" from "d"

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to be able to link current name `d` to `a` in a query. Basically, someone looking up the object, which was originally named `a`, has to be able to reference it by `a`,`b,`,`c`, or `d` but still be able to "get" a file named using `a`'s value.

Assume:

```
object_rename table
--------------------
 new | old
-----|-----
 b   | a
 c   | b
 d   | c
```

Is this possible in a query given this table structure?

(Not sure what title to use here.)

Comment: Do you have a limit of how many steps can you go back?

Comment: i'm guessing you are excluding the possibility of using a programming language w/ it... right?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin - Preferably not. I can solve that if I can limit the steps. Suffice it to say, it wasn't spec'd having more than one generational rename to begin with. I have no idea how volatile the renames are in practice.

Comment: @hummingBird - I have PHP (see my above comment). I can a definite number of steps, but the preference is to query it with `n` number of steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's without limits:

```
SELECT  @id :=
    (
    SELECT  old
    FROM    names
    WHERE   new = @id
    ) AS variable
FROM    (
    SELECT  @id := 'd'
    ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
    names
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
```

Here's a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2531b/3

This has been taken from this question: [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql)

You can probably modify it to give only one answer, but considering the fact you have PHP to work with it, I'll rest my case. I guess you could do it in MySQL by adding an iterator and then selecting from results with maximum iterator value or something alike.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of revisions can be limited, you can use a self join.

Consider table:

```
create table hist_table (new_name varchar(20), old_name varchar(20));
```

Query:

```
select h0.new_name, h1.new_name, h2...
from hist_table h0
left join hist_table h1 on h1.old_name = h0.new_name
left join hist_table h2 on h2.old_name = h1.new_name
...
```

Will give you the basic history result.

Not very effective, but hierarchical queries rarely are.

What I would suggest instead is to reorganize your data:

```
create table hist_table (
   id int primary key
 , object_id int
 , name varchar(20)
 , created timestamp
);
```

I'm omitting not null constraints and indexes.
ID is just a basic sequence. Object Id points to your entity, which probably has more than just a name. Names are all the names object had.

Comment: Yes, with foreknowledge I would've include the unique identifier that links all of them together (in this case, a VIN number). However, it wasn't spec'd as being name-volatile....