# Retrieving categories an sub categories in parent to child order

Tags: php, mysql

I have following Table i want

```
 id | item_name  | parent_id | 
 1  | Shoes      | 0         | 
 2  | Jackets    | 0         | 
 3  | Formal     | 1         | 
 4  | Casuals    | 1         | 
 5  | Party Wear | 2         | 
 6  | Leather    | 5         | 
 7  | Imported   | 6         |
```

Now i want when i run query to get all cateogries of "Jackets" result should be like this

Jackets,Party wear,Leather,Imported|

Comment: what you have *tried* ? Can you show us something ?

Comment: use group by parent_id.

Comment: @AfshanShujat using group by will return only one record for parent id 1 i.e either formal or casual

Comment: Google hierarchical query MySQL

Comment: @Umer iqbal In SO you won't get that you want until you did not try yourself something, show us what you have tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql)

Comment: Suggestion: Use `order by` with `desc` or `asc` with `parent_id`

Comment: For this result you have to write MySQL store procedure. I think better that you have write code in php

Comment: SELECT c.name FROM categories c join categories a on c.id=a.subcategory  where c.id='2' order by a.subcategory desc

Comment: SELECT c.item_name FROM categories c join categories a on c.id=a.parent_id where c.id='2' order by a.parent_id desc