# Finding Top Parent (Recursive)

Tags: php, mysql

Product table:

```
id | id_parent | margin
------------------------
1  | NULL      | 10
2  | 1         | 20
3  | NULL      | 15
4  | 2         | 10
5  | 4         | 25
```

From data above, **how to get margin total of product tree (id: 5)**? It doesn't have fixed depth, it is dynamic.

I currently achieve this with iteration from PHP (recursive mysqli_query), but it consumes huge hosting memory (error 508).

Here is the PHP function:

```
function get_margintotal($product) {
    global $link;

    $query = "SELECT id_parent, margin FROM `products` WHERE id = ".$product['id_parent'];
    if (!$temp_products = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        die(json_encode(array("errmsg" => "Selecting supplier's margin.")));
    }
    $temp_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($temp_products);
    $temp_product['margin'] = $product['margin'] + $temp_product['margin'];

    if (isset($temp_product['id_parent'])) {
        return get_margintotal($temp_product);
    }
    else {
        return $temp_product['margin'];
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering if dynamic iteration can be done in MySQL or how to optimise the function to decrease server memory usage?

Thank you.

Comment: what you tried please share

Comment: In sql CTE helps, so in mysql probably this post will help https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7147

Comment: If your PHP code is well-written, there's no reason it should consume huge memory. You might want to ask a separate question to get help with fixing that.

Comment: @Naincy Updated, please have a look.

Comment: @Simba Updated, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL solution using recursion with variables.

```
CREATE TABLE `finding_top_parent_recursive_46170847` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `margin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `finding_top_parent_recursive_46170847` (`id`, `id_parent`, `margin`)
VALUES
    (1, NULL, 10),
    (2, 1, 20),
    (3, NULL, 15),
    (4, 2, 10),
    (5, 4, 25);


-- set the seed leaf id
set @id = 5 ;
select sum(margin) margin from (
    -- include the seed 
    select id, margin from finding_top_parent_recursive_46170847 products
    where id = @id
    union all
    -- get the parents
    select @id := ( 
        select id_parent 
        from finding_top_parent_recursive_46170847 products
        where id = @id ) id,
        ( select margin 
        from finding_top_parent_recursive_46170847 products
        where id = @id ) margin
    from 
    finding_top_parent_recursive_46170847 products
    where @id is not null
) margins

-- results
margin
65
```

Ideas for recursive mysql results from

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mysql+recursive+left+join

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins

[Hierarchical queries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum depth, let say 5, you can count sum in one query with 4 `LEFT JOINS`:

```
SELECT p1.margin + IFNULL(p2.margin, 0) + IFNULL(p3.margin, 0) + IFNULL(p4.margin, 0) + IFNULL(p5.margin, 0)
FROM product AS p1
    LEFT JOIN product AS p2 ON p1.id_parent = p2.id
    LEFT JOIN product AS p3 ON p2.id_parent = p3.id
    LEFT JOIN product AS p4 ON p3.id_parent = p4.id
    LEFT JOIN product AS p5 ON p4.id_parent = p5.id
WHERE p1.id = :givenId
```

Comment: No, It doesn't have fixed depth. It is dynamic.

Comment: At least can run 5 times less queries when you are doing calculations recursively in PHP. A good solution in such case is to use some nested tree structure in your table, check Nested Sets DB Tree [Nested Sets DB Tree](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/2547-PHP-Manipulate-database-records-in-hierarchical-trees.html).