# get parents and children of tree folder structure in my sql < 8 and no CTEs

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a folder table that joins to itself on an `id`, `parent_id` relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE folders (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
  parent_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) VALUES(1, 'root', null);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) values(2, 'one', 1);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) values(3, 'target', 2);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) values(4, 'child one', 3);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) values(5, 'child two', 3);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) values(6, 'root 2', null);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) values(7, 'other child one', 6);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, parent_id) values(8, 'other child two', 6);
```

I want a query that returns all the parents of that record, right back to the route and any children.

So if I ask for folder with `id=3`, I get records: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. I am stuck how to get the parents.

The version of MYSQL is 5.7 and there are no immediate plans to upgrade so sadly CTEs are not an option.

I have created this [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40b8/1)

Comment: What nesting level does folders might have?

Comment: @MaximFedorov there is no limitation on how deep they can go but I don't see it getting too crazy

Comment: "I am stuck how to get the parents" - But you know how to get the "children"? What about children of children? Don't you need them?

Answer (score 8):

In your table design, `ID` and `PARENT_ID` corresponds to the "**Adjacency List Model**" for storing a tree.

There is another design, called the "**Nested Set Model**", which makes it easier to perform the operations you want here.

See this excellent article from Mike Hillyer describing both:
[managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

In summary:

The tree is stored in a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE nested_category (
        category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        lft INT NOT NULL,
        rgt INT NOT NULL
);
```

Finding the path from the root to a given node (here, 'FLASH'):

```
SELECT parent.name
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.name = 'FLASH'
ORDER BY parent.lft;
```

Finding all children of a given node (here 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS'):

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.name = 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS'
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth <= 1
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

After renaming to your folders table

- TABLE nested_category -> TABLE folders
- Column category_id -> Column id
- Column name -> Column title

The solution is:

```
CREATE TABLE folders (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        lft INT NOT NULL,
        rgt INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(1, 'root', 1, 10);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(2, 'one', 2, 9);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(3, 'target', 3, 8);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(4, 'child one', 4, 5);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(5, 'child two', 6, 7);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(6, 'root 2', 11, 16);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(7, 'other child one', 12, 13);
INSERT INTO folders(id, title, lft, rgt) values(8, 'other child two', 14, 15);
```

Path to the target:

```
SELECT parent.title
FROM folders AS node,
        folders AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.title = 'target'
ORDER BY parent.lft;
```

Target children:

```
SELECT node.title, (COUNT(parent.title) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
    FROM folders AS node,
            folders AS parent,
            folders AS sub_parent,
            (
              SELECT node.title, (COUNT(parent.title) - 1) AS depth
                    FROM folders AS node,
                            folders AS parent
                    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                            AND node.title = 'target'
                    GROUP BY node.title
                    ORDER BY node.lft
            )AS sub_tree
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
            AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
            AND sub_parent.title = sub_tree.title
    GROUP BY node.title
    HAVING depth <= 1
    ORDER BY node.lft;
```

See [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3658c1/1)

To get all the data in a single query, a `union` should do.

Comment: Note that under this model, adding a new item will cost `o(n)` (i.e. it might necessitate update of all rows in the table).

Comment: @JiriTousek Correct, there are pros and cons to this model.

Comment: Nested set model rocks. I suspect this is some kind of an e-commerce. 99,99999% queries are going to be READS anyway, and selecting entire trees it blazing fast. It's really worth it.

Comment: Selecting "parents" is also `O(n)`.

Comment: Best architecture is easy to solve many problems.  Nice one to learn the design. best when least writes are there.

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL 8.0, you can make use of the [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) to adress this use case.

The following query gives you the parents of a given record (including the record itself):

```
with recursive parent_cte (id, title, parent_id) as (
  select id, title, parent_id
  from folders
  where id = 3
  union all
  select  f.id, f.title, f.parent_id
  from folders f
  inner join parent_cte pc on f.id = pc.parent_id
)
select * from parent_cte;
```

```
| id  | title  | parent_id |
| --- | ------ | --------- |
| 3   | target | 2         |
| 2   | one    | 1         |
| 1   | root   |           |
```

And here is a slightly different query, that returns the children tree of a given record:

```
with recursive children_cte (id, title, parent_id) as (
  select id, title, parent_id
  from folders
  where parent_id = 3
  union all
  select  f.id, f.title, f.parent_id
  from folders f
  inner join children_cte cc on f.parent_id = cc.id
)
select * from children_cte;
```

```
| id  | title     | parent_id |
| --- | --------- | --------- |
| 4   | child one | 3         |
| 5   | child two | 3         |
```

Both queriers can be combined as follows:

```
with recursive parent_cte (id, title, parent_id) as (
  select id, title, parent_id
  from folders
  where id = 3
  union all
  select  f.id, f.title, f.parent_id
  from folders f
  inner join parent_cte pc on f.id = pc.parent_id
),
children_cte (id, title, parent_id) as (
  select id, title, parent_id
  from folders
  where parent_id = 3
  union all
  select  f.id, f.title, f.parent_id
  from folders f
  inner join children_cte cc on f.parent_id = cc.id
)
select * from parent_cte
union all select * from children_cte;
```

```
| id  | title     | parent_id |
| --- | --------- | --------- |
| 3   | target    | 2         |
| 2   | one       | 1         |
| 1   | root      |           |
| 4   | child one | 3         |
| 5   | child two | 3         |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i7EeBuznQ1XFZvQwN7gTZe/0)**

Comment: Could have used this functionality years ago, wasn't aware of it.

Comment: It wasn't available in MySQL until version 8.0.1, released April 2017. Other SQL products have had it for some years. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause/325243#325243

Comment: it is a great answer but sadly I'm on 5.7 in the crappy SAS we are using.  I can do it in code but is there a way pre CTE to do this?  Any pointers at all appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this in the past with a second table, which contains the transitive closure of all paths through the tree.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE folders_closure (
 ancestor INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 descendant INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (ancestor, descendant),
 depth INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

Load this table with tuples of all ancestor-descendant pairs, including the ones where a node in the tree references itself (path of length 0).

```
mysql> INSERT INTO folders_closure VALUES
     (1,1,0), (2,2,0), (3,3,0), (4,4,0), (5,5,0), (6,6,0),
     (1,2,1), (2,3,1), (3,4,1), (3,5,1), (1,4,2), (1,5,2),
     (6,7,1), (6,8,1);
```

Now you can query the tree below a given node by querying all the paths that start at the top node, and join that path's descendant to your `folders` table.

```
mysql> SELECT d.id, d.title, cl.depth FROM folders_closure cl
     JOIN folders d ON d.id=cl.descendant WHERE cl.ancestor=1;
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | title     | depth |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | root      |     0 |
|  2 | one       |     1 |
|  4 | child one |     2 |
|  5 | child two |     2 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

I see many people recommend the [Nested Sets solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) which was [introduced in 1992](http://www.infokarta.com/content/relational-taboo-recursive-dimensions-and-topological-ordering-nested-sets), and became popular after Joe Celko included it in his book [SQL for Smarties](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780128007617.do) in 1995. But I don't like the Nested Sets technique, because the numbers aren't actually references to the primary keys of the nodes in your tree, and it requires renumbering many rows when you add or delete a node.

I wrote about the closure table method in [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462) and some of [my other answers with the hierarchical-data tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A20860%20%5Bhierarchical-data%5D).

I did a presentation about it: [Models for Hierarchical Data](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

I also covered this in a chapter of my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: How does the size of the closure table grow, when the number of nodes in the tree (N) grows ?

Comment: In theory, `O(n^2 / 2)` but in practice it's usually less than that.

Comment: I tested with a tree of 518,000 nodes, and if I recall it created fewer than 5 million rows in the closure table.

Comment: @MarcAlff `N²/2` is the worst case - when you have a single chain, which is not really a tree. The exact number is `N * average_depth`. For a balanced binary tree it is `N * log2(N)`, which is something like 20M rows for 1M nodes. But most trees are not binary. For example: The average nesting depth in frequently used tree-style forum will almost stop growing at some point, and you will end up with something like 5x to 10x rows per post. So 5M rows for 500K rows is a realistic number.

Comment: Yes, my test data was the taxonomy of all plants, animals, and fungi from https://www.itis.gov.

Answer (score 3):

If it's guaranteed that child nodes always have a higher id than it's parent, then you could use *user variables*.

Get descendants:

```
select f.*, @l := concat_ws(',', @l, id) as dummy
from folders f
cross join (select @l := 3) init_list
where find_in_set(parent_id, @l)
order by id
```

Result:

```
id | title     | parent_id | dummy
---|-----------|-----------|------
 4 | child one |         3 | 3,4
 5 | child two |         3 | 3,4,5
```

Get ancestors (including itself):

```
select f.*, @l := concat_ws(',', @l, parent_id) as dummy
from folders f
cross join (select @l := 3) init_list
where find_in_set(id, @l)
order by id desc
```

Result:

```
id | title  | parent_id | dummy
 3 | target |         2 | 3,2
 2 | one    |         1 | 3,2,1
 1 | root   |      null | 3,2,1
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kNWLth5HjCQFMgrd6x8RiF/0)

Note that this technique relies on undocumented evaluation order, and will not be possible in future versions.

Also it is not very performant, since both queries need a full table scan, but might be fine for smaller tables. However - for small tables I would just fetch the full table and solve the task with a recursive function in application code.

For bigger tables I would consider a more complex solution like the following *stored procedure*:

```
create procedure get_related_nodes(in in_id int)
begin
  set @list = in_id;
  set @parents = @list;

  repeat
    set @sql = '
      select group_concat(id) into @children
      from folders
      where parent_id in ({parents})
    ';
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '{parents}', @parents);
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    set @list = concat_ws(',', @list, @children);
    set @parents = @children;
  until (@children is null) end repeat;

  set @child = in_id;
  repeat
    set @sql = '
      select parent_id into @parent
      from folders
      where id = ({child})
    ';
    set @sql = replace(@sql, '{child}', @child);
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    set @list = concat_ws(',', @parent, @list);
    set @child = @parent;
  until (@parent is null) end repeat;

  set @sql = '
    select *
    from folders
    where id in ({list})
  ';
  set @sql = replace(@sql, '{list}', @list);
  prepare stmt from @sql;
  execute stmt;
end
```

Use it with

```
call get_related_nodes(3)
```

This will return

```
id | title     | parent_id
---|-----------|----------
 1 | root      | 
 2 | one       | 1
 3 | target    | 2
 4 | child one | 3
 5 | child two | 3
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9fcc2d5cd01847c5f2ea65a30fd735a)

I expect this procedure to perform as good as a *recursive CTE* query. In any case you should have an index on `parent_id`.

Comment: Could you please explain or direct me to a good resource regarding the working style of "cross join (select @l := 3) init_list"? That is a really short code and would like to learn more on it.

Comment: @surpavan `cross join (select @l := 3) init_list` is a "trick" to avoid an extra query `set @l = 3;`. MySQL will execute/evaluate a "constant" subquery like this as the first step (you can see that when you use [EXPLAIN](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7QyB8q5W6GghnMnL5cTFWo/0)). So this line is just initializing the `@l` variable. You will find this "trick" in many other similar answers.

Comment: After some digging, got to some point of understanding; but when i try for the value 7 (code screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/I7S6QJP.png), there are 5 rows with id in @l as per select statement, but when WHERE is applied, it is returning only 2 rows (although it is correct).

Comment: @surpavan `@l := concat_ws(',', @l, id)` in the SELECT clause will append the `id` to `@l`, but only if the WHERE condition is TRUE for that row. IF you remove the WHERE clause, all ids will be appended. If you want to "play around" - try this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vEVeEbLyKuBqCkLfuCz6M4/0

Comment: Actually for "parents" you don't need a list, and can use this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8w1Jrfw4gXZzckudHjKzUz/0

Comment: Great explanation for the flow.  It takes me to 101 sql in execution flow.   Thank you for the valuable time and knowledge sharing.

Comment: Be careful though and read my note in the answer. There is no such thing as "execution flow" or "execution order" in SQL, because SQL is not a procedural language. This only works due to MySQL's internal implementation. They don't want to "break" existing code, which relies on this implementation. But at the same time they need the "freedom" to change things. That's why this technique is **deprecated** and something like `@l := id` will not work in future versions (maybe already in 8.1). But from 8.0 on you better use a *recursive CTE* as suggested by GMB.

Comment: Agreed, Thank you for the note.  I tried the new .net connector, and it really has all new things and the generic way of connecting/executing sql code has changed completely, old code is not working at all. Same goes with the @l execudtion, understood.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if your parent_id comes always in ascending order then below query is the great solution.

if you get the result your id to null parent value then Please follow the link
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40b8/258 (When passing id = 6)
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40b8/259 (When passing id = 3)

```
SELECT * FROM folders f
WHERE id = 3 
OR 
  (Parent_id <=3 AND Parent_id >= 
  (SELECT id FROM folders Where id <= 3 AND parent_id IS NULL Order by ID desc LIMIT 1)) OR (id <= 3 AND IFNULL(Parent_id,0) = 0)
  AND id >= (SELECT id FROM folders Where id <= 3 AND parent_id IS NULL Order by ID desc LIMIT 1);
```

OR

You won't get your passing id to top at parent then please follow the link as below.
 http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40b8/194 (When passing id =3)
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40b8/208 (When passing id =6)

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM 
     folders f
WHERE 
    id = 3 OR Parent_id <=3 
    OR (id <= 3  AND IFNULL(Parent_id,0) = 0);
```

Comment: First, read the answer after check results and if not works then downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote but I know the reason, for 6 you should get 6,7 and 8. but this logic will get everything below a given id and that is wrong.

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran Please check the latest result and if any doubts then tell me.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** My solution is more or less same as @Marc Alff. Didn't realise it was already there before typing / preparing response in an editor.

It is very difficult to get a query to achieve your objective (or other typical requirements of hierarchical dataset) without use of CTEs or other hierarchical query supports (e.g. prior, connect by in Oracle). This was the main driver for databases to come up with CTEs etc.

Many many years ago when such support for modelling hierarchical entities weren't available in databases, requirements outlined by you and many other related were solved by modelling such entities slightly differently.

The concept is simple. In essence, two more attributes are introduced in the hierarchical table (or a separate table foreign keyed into hierarchical table) called left_boundary and right_boundary (call whatever you wish after all what’s in the name). For each row the values (numbers) for these attributes are so chosen that they cover the values of these attributes for all their children. In other words, a child’s left and right boundaries will be between left and right boundaries of its parents.

By the way of example

[image]

Creating this hierarchy used to be part of an early morning batch job or the boundaries were chosen so wide apart during design time that they were easily covering all depths of tree.

I am going to use this solution to achieve your objective.
Firstly I will introduce a second table (could have introduced the attributes in the same table, decided not to disturb your data model)

```
CREATE TABLE folder_boundaries (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  folder_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  left_boundary int(10) unsigned,
  right_boundary int(10) unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES folders(id)
);
```

The data for this table based on your dataset

```
NSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(1, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(2, 2, 9);
INSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(3, 3, 8);
INSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(4, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(5, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(6, 21, 25);
INSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(7, 22, 22);
INSERT INTO folder_boundaries(folder_id, left_boundary, right_boundary) VALUES(7, 22, 22);
```

Here is the query to achieve what you are after

```
select f.id, f.title
from folders f
join folder_boundaries fb on f.id = fb.folder_id
where fb.left_boundary < (select left_boundary from folder_boundaries where folder_id = 3)
and fb.right_boundary > (select right_boundary from folder_boundaries where folder_id = 3)
union all
select f.id, f.title
from folders f
join folder_boundaries fb on f.id = fb.folder_id
where fb.left_boundary >= (select left_boundary from folder_boundaries where folder_id = 3)
and fb.right_boundary <= (select right_boundary from folder_boundaries where folder_id = 3)
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an union between parent rows and child rows like this :

```
select title, id, @parent:=parent_id as parent from
               (select @parent:=3 ) a join (select * from folders order by id desc) b where @parent=id
union select title, id, parent_id as parent from folders where  parent_id=3 ORDER BY id
```

here a sample [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Tkupemh1dc34cfnbBmxbU/2)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know the **maximum depth** of the tree, you could "create" a loop to get what you want:

**Get parent nodes:**

```
SELECT  @id :=
        (
        SELECT  parent_id
        FROM    folders
        WHERE   id = @id
        ) AS folderId, vars.id
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 7 AS id
        ) vars
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS nbr UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 
 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 
 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 
 UNION ALL SELECT 9) temp
WHERE @id IS NOT NULL
```

**Get child nodes:**

```
SELECT  @id :=
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(id)
        FROM    folders
        WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(parent_id, @id)
        ) AS folderIds, vars.id
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 1 AS id
        ) vars
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS nbr UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 
 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 
 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 
 UNION ALL SELECT 9) temp
WHERE @id IS NOT NULL
```

This works by

- Creating a join between a static variable subquery `(SELECT  @id := 1 AS id)` and a static set of 10 rows in this case(maximum depth)
- using a subquery in the select to traverse the tree and find all the parents or child nodes

The purpose of the join is to create a result set of 10 rows, so that the subquery in the select is executed 10 times.

Alternatively, if you do not know the maximum depth, you could **replace the joined subquery** with

```
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 1 FROM folder) temp
```

or in order to avoid all the union selects above, use with a limit:

```
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 1 FROM folder LIMIT 100) temp
```

References:
 - [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql)